Serializing a Kotlin sealed class to a custom JSON structure with kotlinx.serialization
I'm trying to encode a sealed class
        json.encodeToString(
            Filter.NOT(
                Filter.Field(
                    name = "foo", value = "bar"
                )
            )
        )

and output something completely different like
{   
    "not": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}

to exactly match the expected JSON of an API I'm integrating into.
The data structure is a sealed interface (with and, or, xor, etc, but removed for simplicity):
@Serializable
sealed interface Filter {

    ... 
    
    @Serializable
    @SerialName("not")
    class NOT(val not: Filter): Filter

    @Serializable(with = Field.Companion::class)
    data class Field(
        val name: String,
        val value: String
    ) : Filter {

        companion object : KSerializer<Field> {

            override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
                get() = mapSerialDescriptor<String, String>()

            override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Field) {
                println(value)
                encoder.encodeStructure(mapSerialDescriptor<String, String>()) {
                    mutableMapOf("a" to "b", value.name to value.value)
                }
            }
            override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Field = TODO()
        }
    }

If I encodeToString, I currently get:
{
    "not": {
        "type": "kotlin.collections.HashMap"
    }
}

if I remove the custom serializer
{
    "not": {
        "type": "com.jvaas.testing.model.filter.Filter.Field",
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
    }
}

So the type should not be there, and name + value should be encoded "name": "value" instead of "name": name, "value": value to achieve
{   
    "not": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}

Trying with
    @Serializable(with = Field.Companion::class)
    data class Field(
        val name: String,
        val value: String
    ) : Filter {
        companion object : JsonTransformingSerializer<Field>(Field.serializer()) {
            override fun transformSerialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
                return JsonObject(mutableMapOf<String, JsonElement>().apply {
                    put("foo", JsonPrimitive("bar"))
                })
            }
        }
    }


I'm getting

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.jvaas.testing.model.filter.Filter$Field$Companion.serializer()" because "com.jvaas.testing.model.filter.Filter$Field.Companion" is null

Any idea how this can be done?
EDIT: Example JSON added as requested

{
  "filter": {
    "or": [
      {
        "and": [
          {
            "field1_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "field2_id": "A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nand": [
          {
            "field3_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "field4_id": "B"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "xor": [
          {
            "field5_id": "3"
          },
          {
            "field6_id": "C"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nor": [
          {
            "field7_id": "D"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field8": [
                "EF",
                "GHI",
                "JK"
              ],
              "operator": "in"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Modelling the and / or / nor / nand / xor / xnor / not part is the easy part, that just works.
@Serializable
sealed interface Filter {

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("and")
    class AND(val and: List<Filter>) : Filter {
        constructor(vararg and: Filter) : this(and.toList())
    }

    @Serializable
    @SerialName("or")
    class OR(val or: List<Filter>) : Filter {
        constructor(vararg or: Filter) : this(or.toList())
    }

    ...

    @Serializable(with = FieldSerializer::class)
    data class Field(
        val name: String,
        val value: String
    ) : Filter {
        ...
    }

}

also quite intuitive to work with too
 json.encodeToString(
     Filter.NOT(
         Filter.AND(
             Filter.Field(
                 name = "foo", value = "bar"
             ),
             Filter.OR(
                  Filter.Field(
                      name = "stack", value = "overflow"
                  ),
                  Filter.Field(
                       name = "rab", value = "oof"
                  ),
             )

         )
     )
)

The field part however needs to be able to take any dynamic name (let's say for argument sake field[a-zA-Z0-9_]*) plus a value and output
{
    'field_that_can_be_anything_unknown_at_compile_time': 'some value'
}

You'll notice in the example JSON that a field can either have a single value or a list of values. For this StackOverflow question, only consider the single value field as part of the question, I can easily create another field type called FieldIn to handle the list of values and solve it with the same solution that is used for a Field with a single value.

Interesting question. Could you provide an example JSON including a expression with two parameters, such as or or and to get a better understanding of the overall structure you're aiming to achieve?

done, I've added some more context, example JSON and what the AND / OR etc classes looks like

By default, kotlinx.serialization uses a field named "type" to discriminate between the available options in a sealed interface / class hierarchy.
If you don't want to use this mechanism, you can provide your own logic for deserialisation and get rid of the "type" field.
You can combine this with a custom KSerializer for the Filter.Field class.
The following should achieve what you've aimed for.
I've adjusted the type hierarchy to the following:
@Serializable(with = FilterSerializer::class)
sealed interface Filter {

    @Serializable
    class AND(val and: List<Filter>) : Filter {
        constructor(vararg and: Filter) : this(and.toList())
    }

    @Serializable
    class NOT(val not: List<Filter>) : Filter {
        constructor(vararg and: Filter) : this(and.toList())
    }

    @Serializable
    class OR(val or: List<Filter>) : Filter {
        constructor(vararg or: Filter) : this(or.toList())
    }

    @Serializable(with = FieldSerializer::class)
    data class Field(
        val name: String,
        val value: String
    ) : Filter
}

The KSerializers look as follows:
object FieldSerializer : KSerializer<Filter.Field> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor
        get() = mapSerialDescriptor<String, String>()

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Filter.Field {
        return decoder.decodeStructure(descriptor) {
            val name = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 0)
            val value = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 1)

            Filter.Field(name, value)
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Filter.Field) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.name)
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 1, value.value)
        }
    }
}

This encodes your Filter.Field as simple key-value pair. I'm certain there are other ways to achieve this but this works.
In order for the polymorphism to work without the "type" field, you can provide your own JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer that discriminates the different fields based on the keys present in the JSON object.
object FilterSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Filter>(Filter::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<Filter> {
        val key = element.jsonObject.keys.single()

        return when(key) {
            "and" -> Filter.AND.serializer()
            "not" -> Filter.NOT.serializer()
            "or" -> Filter.OR.serializer()
            else -> Filter.Field.serializer()
        }
    }
}

You can try it out with this example:
fun main() {
    val json = Json {
        prettyPrint = true
    }
    val value: Filter = Filter.NOT(
        Filter.AND(
            Filter.Field(
                name = "foo", value = "bar"
            ),
            Filter.OR(
                Filter.Field(
                    name = "stack", value = "overflow"
                ),
                Filter.Field(
                    name = "rab", value = "oof"
                ),
            )

        )
    )

    val encoded: String = json.encodeToString(value)
    println(encoded)

    val decoded: Filter = json.decodeFromString<Filter>(encoded)
    println(decoded)
}


this is beautiful! thanks for taking the time to create this great answer
